# Show an alert dialog/pup-up visible to all users in a Google Spreedsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have Google spreadsheet that it's edited with "Anyone with the link can edit" rights, by multiple people (8-10) at the same time. I am the owner and maintainer of that file and occasionally i want to show an alert dialog with a message to all active users in the file. To do that i am using the following code:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show alert', 'showAlert')
      .addToUi();
}

function showAlert() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

  var result = ui.alert(
     'ATTENTION!',
     'MY ATTENTION MESSAGE...BLA...BLA...BLA.',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK);

}
```

Everything working fine, the alert dialog shows up properly but.... it's visible only to me. No one of the active users in the spreadsheet sees it.

I've try several code alternatives with no luck and also because i read in some sites that only people with "editor" role can see these dialogs, i've try to add the users of the spreadsheet as editors with this code:

```
 Drive.Permissions.insert(
   {
     'role': 'editor',
     'type': 'user',
     'value': 'usermail@examplemail.com'
   },
   fileId,
   {
     'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'
   });
```

Again... no luck!!!.

What am i doing wrong here ?. How can make this work and be able to sent an alert dialog to all types/roles of users in my spreadsheet?

Comment: you are trying to notify the users who are viewing the spreadsheet; if you have their email addresses, why not just email them with whatever information is necessary to know about viewing the spreadsheet? You could also use Slack, Zulip, text messages, Facebook, or Skype or just walk over to their desks and chat with them about it. This problem cannot be solved by writing code for Google Sheets.

Answer (score 2):

Google Sheets / Google Apps Script doesn't include a feature to show an alert / dialog to all the users viewing the spreadsheet and can't make a sheet (tab) as the active tab for all users viewing the spreadsheet either.

You could email, Google Hangouts, Google Hangouts Chat or another similar app to send them an alert.

Comment: @NessusB Besides the fact that what you want to do (show an alert to all spreadsheet users) isn't possible, what do you expect as an answer?

Comment: Thank you for your participation to my issue.

Answer (score -1):

you don't need a menu, just a ui.

I have a similar sheet and use this code.

```
function onOpen() {
    var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

   ui.alert("Greetings! Message here.\n Thanks."); 


}
```

Comment: I don't want to show the alert wherever the spreadsheet is open or reload. I need to do it wherever i need to. It might be 3-4 times in one day or 1 time in one week. Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: Yes, you can't have that kind of control over someone elses ui in sheets.

Comment: So, what's the point of this function ```showAlert()``` if it's visible only to yourself?